# Do expeditions have an expiration date?

Tags: pikmin-bloom

I've got several expeditions for fruits backed up after spending a day away from where I live.  Will these eventually expire or is it possible to eventually complete all of them?  If they don't expire, is there a maximum number to queue or will new ones always pop up?

Comment: I don't have anything definitive, but I think that expeditions to giant flowers might expire when the flower dies?  Not sure about ones other than that though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They definitely expire, after a couple (~5) days. Noticed it for myself, but also mentioned in this [beginner guide](https://www.reddit.com/r/Pikmin/comments/qi1omh/comprehensive_pikmin_bloom_beginner_guide_from_a/) from a Reddit beta tester.